# Selenium ChromeDriver "get" doesn't reliably load @import fonts

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fonts, selenium-chromedriver

I have a few HTML pages like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic); 
body { font-family: 'Droid Serif'; }</style>
</head>
...
```

When loading the page with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
browser.get("http://www.example.com/")
```

then:

- 50% of the time, the font doesn't get loaded (the page is displayed with default serif font (Times New Roman probably))
- 50% of the time, the font is loaded

**How to make font loading more reliable with Selenium?**

Even re-loading the page a second time with `time.sleep(2); browser.get(...)` didn't help 100% of the time.

Comment: Any luck with this? Disappointed to come across this a year later and see there are no answers.

Comment: @user7290573 Feel free to start a 50 or 100-point bounty (I often do in such cases, it helps).

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upoun this Web API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet).

Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

u = 'https://fonts.google.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(u)

while True:
    script = '''return document.fonts.status;'''
    loaded = driver.execute_script(script)
    if loaded == 'loaded':
        print('All fonts loaded')
        break
    print('Fonts still loading')
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Must say that, in my case, chrome return the control to selenium only when the page is fully loaded (including fonts).
Maybe you could provide a minimum example to test your 50-50 scenario

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I commented out `options.add_argument('--headless')` in my script. It would seem (at least in my case) that Chrome only downloads web fonts if they're "truly" visible.